# Fullcalendar: why can't i post array with events?

Tags: javascript, post, fullcalendar

I've added a fullcalendar to my webpage. Now I am trying to implement the database connection to get and set calendar events in the database. It now successfully shows events from the database, but I can't save the events. If I refresh the page, the previously saved events are gone. Also, if I open the inspector in my browser and I hit the network tab, I cannot find a trace of the POST I use and I don't get an alert.

The console shows following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined
at hn.calendar (moment.min.js:1)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.w.param (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
at e.select (selectable.php:59)
at t.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
```

What did I do wrong? Why doesn't it work?

The code I use:

```
select: function (start, end) {
  var title = prompt('Event Title:');
  var eventData;

  if (title) {
    eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end
    };

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
  }

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    $.ajax({
     url: 'setEvent.php',
     data: { eventData : eventData },
     type: "POST",
     success: function(json) {
       alert("done");
     }
  });
},
editable: true,
eventLimit: true,
events: 'getEvent.php',
```

Comment: could it be that `eventData` is undefined ? because it has no title?

Comment: @NiritLevi i don't think so, because the event gets rendered and shown with title and on right start/end datetime.

Comment: @NiritLevi the problem occurs even if the title is completed by the user. But I agree it does seem a little illogical to continue to try and create the event even if the user did not add a title (and therefore the eventData object does not get created properly). Tio can fix that logic if they wish, but it's not the source of the error mentioned. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/475/ for a runnable demo of this problem.

Comment: @ADyson maybe its because the `select` function returns real moment object and you should convert it to ISO string (like using `moment(start).toISOString()` (not from knowing, just thinking at loud )

Comment: @NiritLevi Actually I believe that would work yes, you can use my JSFiddle and update it to test that if you have time. Presumably jQuery does not serialise the moment object correctly. Although `start.toISOString()` would be fine because `start` is already a moment, as you stated yourself. No need to wrap it in another moment constructor!